# Cannot connect mobile app into browser REST api

Tags: android, rest, react-native, drupal-8

I have a working react-native app installed in my mobile device. Also, I have an REST server running in my machine.

**GOAL**

I want that the app should communicate to the REST api server. I am trying to use REST method to fetch data from the site.

**PROBLEM/MOTIVATION**

I was able to use my router's IP address as connection for the app and api.
Below are the URLs that can be accessed in both mobile browser and my machine/laptop browser.

> Api browser debugger-ui runs in
>   http://192.168.254.106:8081/debugger-ui
>
> REST server runs in
>   http://192.168.254.106/open_social

Things I've done so far:
I modified the app using jsonapi(waterwheel) code to fetch or update data from the site.

```
  const Waterwheel = require('waterwheel');
  const waterwheel = new Waterwheel({
    base: 'http://192.168.254.106/open_social',
    timeout: 10000,
    oauth: {
      grant_type: 'password',
      client_id: '2249cb82-98d8-49ea-a32b-a7cff7912a7e',
      client_secret: 'admin',
      username: 'admin',
      password: 'n8hBtuFY8R',
      scope: 'administrator'
    }
  })  

  waterwheel.jsonapi.get('node/test', {}, "1cc692b8-c37c-4ee7-942f-b2e6b8276f35")
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      console.log('Success..!')
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
  })
```

Waterwheel is a module added in the node_modules folder in my app when running `npm install waterwheel`

CORS are also enabled in my api:

```
  cors.config:
    enabled: true
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Access-Cntrol-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization']
    allowedMethods: ['POST', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
    allowedOrigins: ['*']
    exposedHeaders: true
    maxAge: false
    supportsCredentials: true
```

Manifest permission is also enabled

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Expected result: I should be able to get response from the REST api server when this code is added in the app.

I think there is no connection made from the app and api that I need to resolve and need help from this.

TIA

Comment: Can't seem to understand your issue. Any error outputs?

Comment: Hi @Raymund, I updated my issue and hopefully you can get my point. Thanks!

Comment: Silly question.. but did you test if the API link is valid on your browser?

Comment: Yes, it is valid and working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on IOS device? check [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html)!

PS: I don't have enough reputation to make a comment

> By default, iOS will block any request that's not encrypted using SSL.
>   If you need to fetch from a cleartext URL (one that begins with http)
>   you will first need to add an App Transport Security exception. If you
>   know ahead of time what domains you will need access to, it is more
>   secure to add exceptions just for those domains; if the domains are
>   not known until runtime you can disable ATS completely. Note however
>   that from January 2017, Apple's App Store review will require
>   reasonable justification for disabling ATS. See Apple's documentation
>   for more information.

Comment: Its in the tag. I'm testing it in an android device.